# Problem renaming cwac-touchlist package in Java

Tags: java, android, namespaces, package

I am trying to use the cwac-touchlist as a project library inside Eclipse:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist

Everything seems to be working fine, except when I am creating my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.TouchListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tlv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.demo"

    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    tlv:normal_height="64dip"
    tlv:grabber="@+id/icon"
    tlv:remove_mode="slideRight"
/>
```

I get the error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'grabber' in package 'com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.demo'
```

The instructions say to:

```
You will need to change the com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.demo to your own project's package in the tlv namespace declaration.
```

**But I am not sure what to rename this package to?** My project package is called `org.sheehan.activity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then change:

```
xmlns:tlv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.demo"
```

to:

```
xmlns:tlv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.sheehan.activity"
```

Comment: this worked great. Thanks for the awesome support here on SO and on the mailing list.